# How to concatenate a range of ranges ("RoR") in D?

Tags: range, d

What is the best way to lazily concatentate together a range of ranges in D?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`std.algorithm.joiner`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html#joiner). e.g.

```
auto ror = [ [1, 2, 3],  [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ];
auto joined = joiner(ror);
assert(equal(joined, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]));
```

Comment: Oh wow, the documentation is so misleading then. >_< I thought it needs a separator but apparently not... thanks.

Comment: Well, you could have used an empty separator to get the same effect. But it looks like the problem is that the overload which doesn't take a separator is missing its documentation, so it doesn't show up in the online docs.

Comment: Yeah I just didn't bother using an empty separator, since it seemed a little roundabout...

Answer (score 0):

Try chain:

http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#chain

Comment: That doesn't do what I'm asking though.